# PHP Script doesnt return all .PHP files from FTP

Tags: php, ftp

I am using the following script to connect to an FTP server.

The script connects fine to the FTP server but doesn't return any files which have PHP extension, it is blank.Not sure what is the problem. Ideally, it should show all files with the suffix .php.

I tried to change the path $startdir to `/test` or only `test` but it shows blank.

**The Ftp folder structure is**

[image]

**PHP code below**

```
<?php
error_reporting( E_ALL );
ini_set( "display_errors", 1 );

$hostname = "ftp.abc.com";
$username = "dev28@sbc.com";
$password="wsedr";

echo $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];

   $startdir = '/home/public_html/dev21/test'; // absolute path
    $suffix   = "php"; // suffixes to list
    $files = array();
    $conn_id = ftp_connect($hostname);
    $login = ftp_login($conn_id, $username, $password);
    if (!$conn_id) {
        echo 'Wrong server!';
        exit;
    } else if (!$login) {
        echo 'Wrong username/password!';
        exit;
    } else {

        $files = raw_list("$startdir");
    }

    ftp_close($conn_id);

    function raw_list($folder) {
        global $conn_id;
        global $suffix;
        global $files;
        $suffixes = explode(",", $suffix);
        $list     = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, $folder);
        $anzlist  = count($list);
        $i = 0;
        while ($i < $anzlist) {
            $split    = preg_split("/[\s]+/", $list[$i], 9, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
            $itemname = $split[8];
            $endung   = strtolower(substr(strrchr($itemname ,"."),1));
            $path     = "$folder/$itemname";
            if (substr($list[$i],0,1) === "d" AND substr($itemname,0,1) != ".") {
                raw_list($path);
            } else if(substr($itemname,0,2) != "._" AND in_array($endung,$suffixes)) {
                array_push($files, $path);
            }
            $i++;
        }
        return $files;
    }

?>
```

Comment: I just tried it on my ftp server, it worked fine, and i got my list in `$files`

Comment: it shows blank on my server